# Mapping folder to a different server via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Our website currently servers images from a website.com/images/ folder.

Thing is we have limited bandwidth on that server and the images are sucking it up.

We have another server with a lot more free bandwidth.

Is there any way to maps /images/ to goto the other server where we'll upload that folder? This would save us from needing to change the paths of every image across all the pages.

Answer (score 5):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) http://your.images.storage.site/images/$1 [L,QSA,R=302]
```

It requires Apache to have mod_rewrite installed.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://otherwebsite.com/images/$1 [L,R=302]
```